# Sign a jar file exported from Eclipse 3.5?

Tags: eclipse, jar, sign

Is it possible to sign a jar file as you export it from Eclipse 3.5? Or a plugin to allow this to happen?

I can easily export a runnable jar, and sign it myself using jarsigner, but manually doing this every change is not efficient.

Answer (score 4):

If there is no plugin, a possible alternative is to setup an ant script to do the operation for you on demand.

The [JAR Signing](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JAR_Signing) mentions the [Platform-releng-signedbuild script](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform-releng-signedbuild) as an example, completed with [a few tips](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/releng/2008/03/07/jar-signing-tips/).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will look into the ANT script, but I have no expirience at all with ANT.

Answer (score 3):

there's a plugin that can help you, http://jarsigner.sourceforge.net/ you install the plugin in the dropins, configure it in the preferences page and then create the jardesc with a traditional eclipse export as jar. then you right click in the jardesc file and select "Create Signed JAR" and it will create the jarfile and sign it using the selected preferences.

Regards,